# Gulp v4 - tasks ordering issue

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rev

I'm trying to create cahe-buster with gulp-rev and gulp-revReplace, everything works fine when I'm compiling javascript, but the replacement of main css file isn't working as it should, replace always takes the old rev-manifest.json file and not the new - generated by task, I'm assuming that this has something to do with tasks order in gulp series? Because the code is almost the same as for the javascript task, so why is it working diffrently?

This is my gulpfile.js
https://github.com/AdamWojda/35_web_dev_chalange/blob/master/Gulpfile.js

Answer (score 1):

Runtime looks like this:

```
| watch
|--
  | generate_js              generate_css
  |-- compress_javascript  |-- generate_styles
  |-- revreplace           |-- revreplace
```

It's possible that `revreplace` from one task rewrite content of `manifest.json` from second one. [jamesknelson](https://github.com/jamesknelson) in documentation use reverse way

```
gulp.task("revision", ["dist:css", "dist:js"], function(){
    return gulp.src(["dist/**/*.css", "dist/**/*.js"])
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(opt.distFolder))
        .pipe(rev.manifest())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(opt.distFolder))
})
```

where each `revision` task execute first `dist:css` and `dist:js` and finally rewrite (once) `manifest.json`. I recommend to change way of tasks' execution (`watch -> revreplace -> generate_js && generate_css`).